# Can't change REST path specified in @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jax-rs

I'm using Netbeans and I have a REST service -

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {
}
```

If I change the "webresources" string to something else and then rebuild the project this 
string automatically gets reset back to "webresources".

So how can I alter the path so that it doesn't reset?

Comment: Weird thing. Which NB version? I am not able to reproduce on 7.2 windows32

Comment: You have to change the "webresources" string first in the project.properties file (in ./nbproject/) : rest.resources.path=resources, then you can edit the "@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("resources")". In my example, I have change "webresources" to "resources".